# Use stunnel for Socket.io SSL support

Tags: linux, node.js, stunnel, socket

I am trying to add SSL support to my `node.js` app, while connecting via `socket.io`. The traffic to `socket.io` is going to port 80. I would like `stunnel` to grab encrypted traffic from port 443, unencrypt it, and forward it to post 80.

I have private.key, certificate and public key at hand, and I couldn't find how I should configure them all to work.

An example of working configuration file for `stunnel` would be great. I had a look at [Websockets Over SSL: Stunnel, Varnish, Nginx, Node.js](https://www.exratione.com/2012/08/websockets-over-ssl-stunnel-varnish-nginx-nodejs/), [Websockets Over SSL: Stunnel, HAProxy, Node.js](http://afitnerd.com/2012/08/14/websockets-over-ssl-stunnel%20haproxy%20node-js) and this [gist](https://gist.github.com/mbenedettini/5911415), but couldn't use any of them to achieve my goal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a problem with the certificate file. In case anyone else will have issues, this is what I eventually did:

**The PEM file**

the file structure of the file should be as follow:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
.
.
.
.
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
.
.
.
.
.
.
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

**/etc/stunnel/stunnel.conf**

The stunnel configuration file:

```
cert = /etc/stunnel/stunnel.pem
[node]
accept = 443
connect = 80
```